# Ubuntu Server 18.04 no IPV4 after resume

Tags: 18.04, netplan, resume, ipv4

I fail to get ipv4 working on an ubuntu server 18.04 after it was suspended and resumed. The only way I get ipv4 running again is reboot. The system is installed as a guest in a vmware virtual machine.

before resume:

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.96  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe1c:7d22  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:0c:29:1c:7d:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 4554  bytes 1079672 (1.0 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 917  bytes 77010 (77.0 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

lshw -C network tells me amongst other things:

```
driver=e1000
```

after resume:

```
ens33: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:0c:29:1c:7d:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 4632  bytes 1087029 (1.0 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 919  bytes 77160 (77.1 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

after ifconfig ens33 up:

```
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe1c:7d22  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:0c:29:1c:7d:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 4666  bytes 1090488 (1.0 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 924  bytes 77606 (77.6 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I see no IP v4 address. After googling I tried

```
# modprobe -r e1000
# modprobe -i e1000
```

but it does not change anything in the output of ifconfig. The only thing that seems to help is shutdown -r...

Any advice what else I could try?